# applying a jquery plugin: loudev.com multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, multi-select

I've got an AJAX call that reloads a multi-select. This is the AJAX I'm using:

```
function cargaValues(paramId){
    var xmlhttp;   
    if (paramId=="-1"){
        document.getElementById("paramValuesTableDiv").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("paramValuesTableDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            **$('#valuesList').multiSelect();** //<-----------------
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/copal/retrieveParamValues.action?selectedId="+paramId+"&inputId="+inputId,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

On the server it finds the values of the selection on bbdd, and it fills them on a list. After that it returns a jsp only containing the select, so its reloaded every time. This is the jsp with the multi-select:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
[...]
    <s:select id="valuesList" name="input.submittedValues" listKey="id" listValue="name" list="input.values" multiple="true"  />
[...]
```

This code is translated more or less as this:

```
<select name="input.submittedValues" id="valuesList" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="49">prepaid</option>
    <option value="50">postpaid</option>
</select>
```

The thing is that I want to apply the [loudev](http://loudev.com/#home) plugin, but when the converting function `$('#valuesList').multiSelect();` is called its constantly giving the error: `“Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined”`

I've also tried to comment it and call it on the browser console (F12), and it gives the same error. Obviously I've got the `.JS` and the `.CSS` included on my jsp.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!
I was using an old version of jquery (1.2.6) and this plugin only works on 1.8+

Thank you all!